# Does the .NET framework violate SOLID principles?

Tags: .net, solid

I see some classes in the .net framework that support reading and writing, saving and loading, classes whose main responsibility is not them, for instance the Stream classes and the XML Dom/XLinq classes.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: I think if you focused this question on one of the classes, I'd be willing to up-vote (I wasn't the down-voter).

Comment: The problem with this question is it assumes the so-called SOLID principles are a positive thing. I am not saying the the .net framework is well designed in all aspects, but SOLID usually leads to overly complex designs, which no one really wants.

Answer (score 6):

Let's touch on these one by one.

**S is for Single Responsibility**

- The single responsibility for XMLDocument is to provide APIs for traversing an XML document
- Yes, its interface has methods for saving and loading, but the *implementation* of XMLDocument doesn't actually save or load. It parses or unparses with respect to a abstraction, a "stream," which you'd have to supply to the XMLDocument in order for those methods to work. Parsing and unparsing is naturally associated with traversal. Persistence isn't handled by the class itself.
- Stream and StreamReader/Writer classes also do this.  They work on logical representations, a theoretical infinite byte array, which is actualized in one of the subtypes, such as a `MemoryStream` or `FileStream`.

**O is for open/closed**

Moot. All framework classes are closed to modification, unless you are doing something *really* weird.

**L is for Liskov Substitution**

Pretty sure you can substitute any type of stream when a steam is needed; whoever is using the stream generally won't care if it's a stream that goes to memory, to disk, or to a network connection. If there are differences in capability (e.g. a maybe a network stream doesn't provide random access) those capabilities are discoverable via properties in the base class, e.g. `CanSeek`.

**I is for Interface Segregation**

Microsoft has been a bit slow on providing interfaces for many of its classes. That being said, you can easily write code that works with abstract base types instead of concrete types, e.g. you can write code that works with any type of stream as long as it inherits from `BaseStream`.

**D is for Dependency Inversion**

XMLDocument and the stream classes both use dependency injection, following the principle of inversion of control. In fact StreamReader and StreamWriter are two of the earliest examples of this principle, since they take the underlying stream as a constructor argument (via a stream's abstract base implementation, which is as good as accepting an interface). XMLDocument uses DI by allowing an abstract base stream to be injected as a method argument to Save or Load.

So no, I don't agree with you, I think the .NET framework does a decent job of following SOLID.

Comment: I certainly agree it does a good job generally, especially in newer parts of the framework, but the oldest parts of the framework have some very Un-SOLID examples such as [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What is it about DataGrid that troubles you?

Comment: Dear is for "Dependency inversion", not for Dependency injection. Big difference. Injection is an approach you use to follow inversion principle

Comment: It's hard to imagine anything in Winforms that could be held up as a model for SOLID.  Nevertheless, the rest of the framework is, er, solid.

Comment: Robert, by reputation alone I trust your comment, but I am curious what you think the problems are with win forms, and if you know of a fat client UI framework (in any language) that would get good grades for SOLID. I'm so stuck in my Microsoft mindset I can't picture a different way.

Comment: The most obvious example of where the framework laughs in the face of SOLID is with the `NotImplementedException` and `NotSupportedException` and the whole mess around `IReadOnlyList` inheriting from `IList`. Oh and all those static IO classes, and all those side-effect classes that don't implement interfaces... but aside from all that, yeah it's reasonably solid (if you don't lean on it too much...)

Comment: I would say that .Net framework falls down on the "open to modification" part of the O/C principle, particularly when compared to Java land. Very few of the class members in .Net are marked as virtual, where as it's the default for Java. It's *sometimes* possible via composition and inheriting from an abstract base, but it can be argued that this is more tedious than need be.